# How do I find the C# Documentation for Nesper?

Tags: c#, .net, esper, nesper

I already read the Java documentation. Unfortunately the Java API and C# API are quite different.

I am trying to implement a CSV-Adapter for the Nesper CEP Framework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That? http://esper.espertech.com/release-6.1.0/esper-reference/html/index.html

Comment: I am familiar with that Documentation. It only covers the Java API. Or am I missing here something? Should I be able to read the Java Doc and understand the C# version of it?

Comment: The only informations that i fou about .Net is that: http://esper.espertech.com/release-6.1.0/esper-reference/html_single/index.html#appendix_dotnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the EsperTech Support Team, I found out that they do not have a seperate documentation for NEsper but the official actually appeals to both (Java and .NET).

They also mentioned that the Regression project in the main NEsper prject is a good reference if you need examples.

I think the best examples are in the `Examples` folder of the `NEsperAll.sln` project.